# Python match case shows error with list element as case. Expected ":"

Tags: python, switch-statement, python-3.10

Hi I was using the newly added match case function but I encountered this problem.

Here's my code:

```
from typing import List

class Wee():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.lololol: List[str] = ["car", "goes", "brrrr"]

    def func1(self):
        self.weee = input()
        try:
            match self.weee:
                case self.lololol[0]:
                    print(self.lololol[0])
                case self.lololol[1]:
                    print(self.lololol[1])
                case _:
                    print(self.lololol[2])
        except SyntaxError as e:
            print(e)

waa = Wee()
waa.func1()
```

At line 11 and 13, errors show up saying `SyntaxError: expected ':'`. However, when I change `case self.lololol[0]:` to `case "car":`, the errors disappear. What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use arbitrary expressions as patterns (since that would sometimes be ambiguous), only [a certain subset](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#id2).

If you want to match against the elements of a list, you should probably, depending on the situation, either make them separate variables, or use `list.index`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `match` `case` statement is intended for **structural** matching. Specifically [PEP 635](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/) says:

> Although patterns might superficially look like expressions, it is important to keep in mind that there is a clear distinction. In fact, no pattern is or contains an expression. It is more productive to think of patterns as declarative elements similar to the formal parameters in a function definition.

Specifically, plain variables are used as capture patterns and not as match patterns - definitely **not** what a C/C++ programmer could expect... - and functions or subscripts or just not allowed.

On a practical point of view, only litteral or dotted expressions can be used as matching patterns.